# Showing that an algorithm is a gradient descent method

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I am stuck on a question about gradient descent, it asks to "show that that the perceptron learning algorithm is a gradient descent method for the squared error target function $(y - \sum w_ix_i)^2$". I understand that by going through the perceptron algorithm the squared error target function will be decreased from one step of the algorithm to the next, but in general, how do I show that an algorithm is a gradient descent method for something?

Comment: The gradient descent iteration for minimizing $f$ is $x^+ = x - t \nabla f(x)$.  You could write this out explicitly for your particular $f$ and see if the iteration you get is the same as the perceptron algorithm.

Comment: ok that makes sense, just to clarify I'm assuming $\nabla$ is the learning rate, but what would $t$ be?

Comment: Hi, @VividD; I see that you've been editing a lot of old posts in the last few minutes. This fills up the front page, and forces newer content off. Editing old posts to improve them is a good thing, but please limit it to a few ($2-3$ per day). In particular, please limit very minor edits, such as adding a single tag.

Comment: @T. Bongers I didn't know it has such an impact. Once I saw your rejections (and you asked me there also to limit edits), I limited my edits but to 1 in 3 min. :)

Comment: @T. Bongers Can I just submit several more minor edits for today, and I am done? Please.

Comment: @VividD I would strongly suggest waiting until tomorrow to suggest any more edits; I think you've edited $18$ posts today, and I would suggest limiting minor edits to old questions to perhaps $3$ a day.

Comment: @T. Bongers OK. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating littleOs's comment:

The gradient descent iteration for minimizing f is $$x \leftarrow x−t\nabla f(x)$$. You could write this out explicitly for your particular f and see if the iteration you get is the same as the perceptron algorithm

Note that, $t $ is the learning rate, and $\nabla f(x)$ is the derivative of the cost function. Now take the derivative of your cost function with respect to input and put in this iteration.